# Magento 1: Access denied admin login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, access

[image]

1> shows access denied while login the admin (Magento 1.9)... actually tried to Rest-API for 3rd party integration for customer users role.
   2> I do not have database details. the client did not provide.
    please guide how can resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset admin password.Go to phpmyadmin and run following command.

```
 UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('irs123456') WHERE `username` = 'admin';
```

username: **admin**
password: **irs123456**

Still facing any problem add comment.I will try to help you.

Comment: Aissyass thanks to your suggestion.. but mentioned before, the client did not provide database details.

Comment: So you can't, ask him to execute this command..

Comment: yes right .....  now any other way to login?

Comment: @irshad I think no !